# Does setting an NSMutableDictionary to nil release the reference to all it's content?

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, memory-management, nsmutabledictionary

So let's say I have an `NSMutableDictionary` filled with objects like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    someClass* tmp = [[someClass alloc] init];
    [dict setObject:tmp forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];
}
```

If I set the dictionary itself equal to `nil`, does that release all the objects I put in it (thus freeing the allocated memory for each one)?

I want to use an `NSMutableDictionary` as a cache basically, and whenever my app receives a call from the system to `didReceiveMemoryWarning`, I want to clear out this cache and release every object in it.

So is setting the dictionary to `nil` enough, or do I have to call some method to wipe out the data and free all the memory allocated by creating `someClass` instances?

Comment: Can you think of a way to test it? Can you test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no another references to dictionary

```
dict = nil;
```

will cause dict deallocation. Deallocation method will be called - [NSMutableDictionary dealloc]. And inside this method all references to its content will be released.

You also cal call NSMutableDictionary's

```
- (void)removeAllObjects;
```

method instead.

I also suggest you to look at NSCache class - it already handles didReceiveMemoryWarning itself:

> An NSCache object is a collection-like container, or cache, that
>   stores key-value pairs, similar to the NSDictionary class. Developers
>   often incorporate caches to temporarily store objects with transient
>   data that are expensive to create. Reusing these objects can provide
>   performance benefits, because their values do not have to be
>   recalculated. However, the objects are not critical to the application
>   and can be discarded if memory is tight. If discarded, their values
>   will have to be recomputed again when needed.

and NSMapTable:

> NSMapTable is a mutable collection modeled after NSDictionary but
>   provides different options.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will use NSCache instead.

Comment: When you set the dictionary tot nil all the items in the dictionary have their retain count decreased by one. If somebody else is stille holding a reference tot an item in the dictionary, this item is nog deallocated. Since it still has a retain count.